# Write a file using System Command

Tags: r, shell, cmd, echo

I am trying to create a file using the system command but it does not work for some reason. It just echoes the command back.

```
system("echo 'Hello2222, world.' >foo2.txt");
Hello2222, world. >foo2.txt
```

When I run the echo command in CMD, the file is created.

Comment: BTW, note that invoking a shell is unsafe to do with non-constant data -- which is to say that it's a much better practice to use R's file I/O primitives if you're doing anything more complex than "hello, world".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the documentation for `system` says

> On Windows, system does not use a shell and there is a separate
>   function shell which passes command lines to a shell.

```
shell("echo 'Hello2222, world.' >foo2.txt")
```

will do what you want.